# neo4j spatial cypher withinDistance issue

Tags: neo4j

I am having trouble getting `withinDistance` to work correctly in Cypher.

I am able to create a layer, add geometries, invoke the index and query using the spatial REST `findGeometriesWithinDistance` with no problems.

1. `POST /db/data/ext/SpatialPlugin/graphdb/addEditableLayer {"layer":"yada"}`
2. `POST /db/data/ext/SpatialPlugin/graphdb/addGeometryWKTToLayer { "layer":"yada","geometry":"LINESTRING (-87.8269667076541 42.5931258671059,-87.8280193743192 42.5930348004394,-87.8284217076519 42.5931722004391)"}`
3. `POST /db/data/ext/SpatialPlugin/graphdb/addGeometryWKTToLayer {"layer":"yada","geometry":"LINESTRING (-87.8118643076776 42.588086600447,-87.8183341743342 42.5876782004477,-87.818426974334 42.5877468671142)"}`
4. `POST /db/data/index/node/ {"name":"yada", "config":{"provider":"spatial","wkb":"wkb"}}`
5. `POST /db/data/ext/SpatialPlugin/graphdb/findGeometriesWithinDistance {"layer":"yada","distanceInKm":2,"pointX":-87.845556,"pointY":42.582222}`

However when I call `withinDistance` using Cypher, e.g.

- `POST /db/data/cypher {"query":"START n=node:yada('withinDistance:[-87.845556,42.582222,10.0]') RETURN n"}`

I get back

```
400 Bad Request
{
  "message" : "only within, WITHINDISTANCE and bbox are implemented.",
  "exception" : "BadInputException",
  "stacktrace" : [ "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.RepresentationExceptionHandlingIterable.exceptionOnHasNext(RepresentationExceptionHandlingIterable.java:50)", "org.neo4j.helpers.collection.ExceptionHandlingIterable$1.hasNext(ExceptionHandlingIterable.java:60)", "org.neo4j.helpers.collection.IteratorWrapper.hasNext(IteratorWrapper.java:42)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.ListRepresentation.serialize(ListRepresentation.java:58)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.Serializer.serialize(Serializer.java:75)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.MappingSerializer.putList(MappingSerializer.java:61)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.CypherResultRepresentation.serialize(CypherResultRepresentation.java:57)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.MappingRepresentation.serialize(MappingRepresentation.java:42)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.OutputFormat.assemble(OutputFormat.java:179)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.OutputFormat.formatRepresentation(OutputFormat.java:131)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.OutputFormat.response(OutputFormat.java:117)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.OutputFormat.ok(OutputFormat.java:55)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.web.CypherService.cypher(CypherService.java:75)", "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)" ],
  "cause" : {
    "message" : "only within, WITHINDISTANCE and bbox are implemented.",
    "exception" : "UnsupportedOperationException",
    "stacktrace" : [ "org.neo4j.gis.spatial.indexprovider.LayerNodeIndex.query(LayerNodeIndex.java:277)", "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.spi.gdsimpl.GDSBackedQueryContext$$anon$1.indexQuery(GDSBackedQueryContext.scala:83)", "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.executionplan.builders.IndexQueryBuilder$$anonfun$getNodeGetter$2.apply(IndexQueryBuilder.scala:83)", "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.executionplan.builders.IndexQueryBuilder$$anonfun$getNodeGetter$2.apply(IndexQueryBuilder.scala:81)", "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.StartPipe$$anonfun$internalCreateResults$1.apply(StartPipe.scala:36)", "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.pipes.StartPipe$$anonfun$internalCreateResults$1.apply(StartPipe.scala:35)", "scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)", "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.ClosingIterator$$anonfun$hasNext$1.apply$mcZ$sp(ClosingIterator.scala:36)", "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.ClosingIterator$$anonfun$hasNext$1.apply(ClosingIterator.scala:35)", "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.ClosingIterator$$anonfun$hasNext$1.apply(ClosingIterator.scala:35)", "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.ClosingIterator.failIfThrows(ClosingIterator.scala:86)", "org.neo4j.cypher.internal.ClosingIterator.hasNext(ClosingIterator.scala:35)", "org.neo4j.cypher.PipeExecutionResult.hasNext(PipeExecutionResult.scala:142)", "scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)", "scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$IteratorWrapper.hasNext(Wrappers.scala:29)", "org.neo4j.helpers.collection.ExceptionHandlingIterable$1.hasNext(ExceptionHandlingIterable.java:58)", "org.neo4j.helpers.collection.IteratorWrapper.hasNext(IteratorWrapper.java:42)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.ListRepresentation.serialize(ListRepresentation.java:58)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.Serializer.serialize(Serializer.java:75)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.MappingSerializer.putList(MappingSerializer.java:61)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.CypherResultRepresentation.serialize(CypherResultRepresentation.java:57)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.MappingRepresentation.serialize(MappingRepresentation.java:42)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.OutputFormat.assemble(OutputFormat.java:179)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.OutputFormat.formatRepresentation(OutputFormat.java:131)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.OutputFormat.response(OutputFormat.java:117)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.OutputFormat.ok(OutputFormat.java:55)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.web.CypherService.cypher(CypherService.java:75)", "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)" ]
  }
```

I am not sure when this behavior started but it seems to be something recent.  Am I doing something wrong here?

Thanks,
Paul

- neo4j 1.9.M05
- neo4j spatial 0.11
- jdk1.7.0_17

Comment: does changing the letter case from `withinDistance` to `WITHINDISTANCE` make it any better?

Comment: No, I think that's typo in the source code (https://github.com/neo4j/spatial/blob/master/src/main/java/org/neo4j/gis/spatial/indexprovider/LayerNodeIndex.java), line 278 says "only %s, %S and %s are implemented."

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem where the REST request would work but the Cypher did not. The solution was to create another "normal" node index (i.e. lucene index, not a spatial one) in the standard way and name it the same as your spatial index.

In your example you create a spatial index called `yada`, to make the Cypher work you would then do what is described [here](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/rest-api-indexes.html) and make a standard neo4j node index, then add your nodes to it.

Then you can do the withinDistance queries via Cypher. Point to not though, this won't let you do standard Cypher queries like `START n=node:yada('*:*') RETURN n;` it will only let you do the spatial queries.

This was with Neo4j 1.9 on Windows.

Comment: still not work, when using another "normal" node index with legacy index, I use neo4j 2.2.1